# Create a script that makes two touch command in the right order always

Tags: bash, shell

For performing one task, I need to make two touch commands in a precise order:
touch aaaa-ref-bbb.done
touch cccc-grp-dddd.done

Beinng aaaa .. dddd any kind of strings. The first string contains "-ref-" and the second string contains "-done-"

I want to make a script that applies both touch commands, independently of the orders that the parameters are passed.

For instance (parameters in the wrong order)

./script.sh  bla-grp-bla   bleh-ref-bleh

Will produce an output of

touch bleh-ref-bleh
touch bla-grp-bla

If the parameters are written in the right order, the touch commands follow the right order.

I have done several tries and each change goes closer to the goal, but now I'm stuck. 
Could you help with this?

```
#### tool for touch debug mode (set -x / set +x)
#!/bin/bash
#
#### USAGE

##### Constants

#start debug code
exec 5> >(logger -t $0)
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -x

FIRSTPARAM=$1
SECONDPARAM=$2

echo $FIRSTPARAM
echo $SECONDPARAM

dotouch()
{
if [[ "$FIRSTPARAM" =~ 'ref' ]]; then
  echo 'correct order, processing...'
  sleep 3
  firsttouch = $FIRSTPARAM'.done'
  secondtouch = $SECONDPARAM'.done'
  echo $firsttouch
  touch $firsttouch
  sleep 1
  touch $secondtouch
  echo "touch was"  $1 $2

else
  secondtouch = $FIRSTPARAM'.done'
  firstouch = $SECONDPARAM'.done'
  touch $firsttouch
  sleep 1
  touch $secondtouch
  echo "touch was"  $2 $1
fi
}

if      [ "$FIRSTPARAM" =~ "ref" ] || [ "$FIRSTPARAM" =~ "grp" ]; then
          dotouch()
          echo "touch commands executed"
          exit 0
else
          echo "Usage: $0 [xxxx_ref_xxxx.tar] [xxxx_grp_yyyy.tar] "
          exit 1

fi
  exit 0
#end debug code
set +x
```

Comment: Can you please read again your question and fix the errors? Example: in the first sentence you give examples of file names, in the second sentence you state that one string contains `-ref-` which is true but you also state that the other contains `-done-` which is not true. Then, your script uses variable names that are obviously wrong (see asalamon74's answer). Please help us helping you.

Comment: I have fixed as many errors as I have found. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Your two first example strings still do not contain the `-done-` sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `2sttouch` and `1ndtouch` variables and using `firsttouch` and `secondtouch`. You should use the same variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not considering the different cases on the main `if` before entering to the `dotouch` function. In your expression you are only evaluating the first parameter so you don't really know the content of the second parameter.

My suggestion is:

- Create a `doTouch` function that simply touches 2 received parameters in the order they are received.
- Add the different cases on the `main` code (if there are more, add more `elif` statements).

Here is the code (without the debug annotations):

```
#!/bin/bash

#######################################                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# Script function helpers
#######################################
doTouch() {
  local ref=$1
  local grp=$2

  echo "Touching $ref"
  touch "$ref"

  echo "Touching $grp"
  touch "$grp"

  echo "Touching order was: $ref $grp"
}

usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [xxxx_ref_xxxx.tar] [xxxx_grp_yyyy.tar]"
}

#######################################
# Main
#######################################

# Retrieve parameters
FIRSTPARAM=$1
SECONDPARAM=$2

echo $FIRSTPARAM
echo $SECONDPARAM

# Check parameter order and touch
if [[ $FIRSTPARAM == *"ref"* ]] && [[ $SECONDPARAM == *"grp"* ]]; then
  doTouch $FIRSTPARAM $SECONDPARM
elif [[ $SECONDPARAM == *"ref"* ]] && [[ $FIRSTPARAM == *"grp"* ]]; then
  doTouch $SECONDPARM $FIRSTPARAM
else
  usage
  exit 1
fi

# Regular exit
exit 0
```

Comment: I have tried your code. I like it's efectiveness & simplicity.  I am getting a wierd error in the IF statements. I have tried several quotes styles (double, execution quotes, etc.) and I am getting the same error:./ingest-tmob.sh: line 36: [: =~: binary operator expected.

Comment: I have enabled debug: ./ingest-tmob.sh  pito-ref poto-grp
+ FIRSTPARAM=pito-ref
+ SECONDPARAM=poto-grp
+ echo pito-ref
pito-ref
+ echo poto-grp
poto-grp
+ '[' pito-ref '=~' ref ']'
./ingest-tmob.sh: line 36: [: =~: binary operator expected
+ '[' poto-grp '=~' ref ']'
./ingest-tmob.sh: line 38: [: =~: binary operator expected
+ usage
+ echo 'Usage: ./ingest-tmob.sh [xxxx_ref_xxxx.tar] [xxxx_grp_yyyy.tar]'
Usage: ./ingest-tmob.sh [xxxx_ref_xxxx.tar] [xxxx_grp_yyyy.tar]
+ exit 1

Comment: @user1006082 For string comparison I prefer to use `[[ STR == *SUB_STR* ]]` but in the previous answer I left it as it was. See my update

Comment: @user1006082 Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by putting your shebang line in the right place, and drastically simplifying the code;

```
#!/bin/bash
#### tool for touch debug mode (set -x / set +x)

exec 5> >(logger -t $0)
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -x

FIRSTPARAM=$1
SECONDPARAM=$2

echo $FIRSTPARAM
echo $SECONDPARAM

dotouch() {
touch "$1"
echo "$Just touched $1"
return 
}


case $FIRSTPARAM in
*"ref"*) dotouch $FIRSTPARAM'.done' ; dotouch $SECONDPARAM'.done' ;;
*"grp"*) dotouch $SECONDPARAM'.done' ; dotouch $FIRSTPARAM'.done' ;;
*) echo "Usage: $0 [xxxx_ref_xxxx.tar] [xxxx_grp_yyyy.tar] " ; exit 1 ;;
esac



exit 0
#end debug code
set +x
```

There was no need for most of that.